# Install binary (gactions) in App engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, actions-on-google

How can I make the GActions CLI available within my Go (1.11) app that's hosted via App Engine Standard?

https://developers.google.com/assistant/tools/gactions-cli

The page that describe the capabilities for App Engine Standard says that it "Supports installing third-party binaries", but I can't find any documentation that shows how.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have dug into this and, as I see it, with "third-party binaries" it means "third-party binary dependencies", thus, libraries. You cannot install other third-party binaries on GAE standard. You can learn how to import the dependencies using the [Go package manager](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/specifying-dependencies).

Regardless, if you truly need this tool, I believe that you may be interested in using GAE flex. It allows you to create a [Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) where you could write a Dockerfile that installs GActions CLI.

Comment: Think you're right. So, I used docker for the first time and App Engine Flex and it seems to be working :D